# Cannot find module 'graphql-hooks' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, graphql

What can I do to install graphql-hooks in react-native TypeScript? How can I define the types?

I have already installed using npm but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

React native (including TypeScript) shouldn't bee any different than any other project:

```
npm install graphql-hooks
```

Perhaps your project is using `yarn`?

```
yarn add graphql-hooks
```

When I try that in a standard create-react-app, it works and gets the TypeScript types immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think graphql-hooks comes with typings. However, a little hack is to create your own custom types. i.e

Create an `index.d.ts` file and insert the following code

```js
declare module 'graphql-hooks' {
    const noTypesYet: any;
    export default noTypesYet;
}
```

Here is a decent article on creating custom types https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-solutions/typescript-adding-custom-type-definitions-for-existing-libraries/